# upload base64 format file from java script to java

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I want to upload Base64 image to server . I am using jsp and js as front end client side and java as back end .

```
var imgData =imagesScanned.data;
    JSON.stringify(imgData)
    var fileShareDetails = {
        pageMode : "SCAN_FILE_UPLOAD",
        imgData:imgData,        
    };

    var d = $.param(fileShareDetails);

    $.ajax({
        url: "folderNavigation.do?" + d,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: imgData,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
            alert("response is coming")
        }
    });
```

If i upload from this i am getting below error

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET http://localhost:9080/Initial/folderNavigation.do?pageMode=SCAN_FILE_UPLOAD…2FWi4XFMrY7Ukb5dqDgj7o%2FWo0VYySowSeckn%2BdK4XJmetKsdnNbFJkn%2F%2F2Q%3D%3 ......
```

Please somebody help me as i have stuck up with this from several hours.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put a huge parameter into the URL.

Put all the parameters, or at least the `imgData` into the request body only.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "folderNavigation.do?" + d,    // remove the "+d"
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: imgData,         // this part goes into the body,
                           // maybe you want "fileShareDetails" 
                           // instead of "imgData"
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data) {
        alert("response is coming")
    }
});
```